# adding items with ngFor with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Im trying to list some data from 2 different arrays - I need to keep the arrays seperate so i can differenciate between the data. I also need to add a class on items from the first array.

I've tried:

```
<div class="divInput" id="divC">
    <div class="divTextInput">
        <input /><button>Add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="CWrapper" class="tableWrapper">
        <div class="cell" *ngFor="let c1 of data.c1">
            <p title={{c1}}>{{c1}}</p><span></span>
         </div>
        <div class="cell kle" *ngFor="let c2 of data.c2">
            <img src={{imagePath}}>
            <p title={{c2}}>{{c2}}</p><span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The kle class doesnt add any css, it's just there so i can differentiate between the two, and do trigger events.

Where the data class is:

```
class Data {
    c1: string[];
    c2: string[];
}
```

Adding to the array with:

```
$('#divC .divTextInput button').on('click', (ev) => {
    let button = $(ev.currentTarget);
    let input = button.prev();
    if (input.val()) {
        this.data.c1.push(<string>input.val());
        this.data.c2.push(<string>input.val());
    }
});
```

When i add a string to c2, it adds it to the html, but when i add a string to c1 it doesnt add to the html (Only div with class="cell kle" is added)

It adds the data that initially is in the array, but not when i add dynamically

If i log the arrays, they both have the added string.

-- *Update* --

It works if the arrays arent in a class.

Comment: Does `kle` class have something like `display: none` property?

Comment: Can you share how do you add the data as well as the css classes you applied?

Comment: The kle class is just to differentiate between the two, it doesnt add any css

Comment: can you show please the code that add a string to `c2` ? which is not working.

Comment: does 'imagePath' property exist on the component class?

Comment: Updated the question with the code that adds the strings.

Comment: imagePath is working yes :)

Comment: Update: it works when the arrays arent in a class